# How to parse object key from handlebars partials.

Tags: express, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper, express-handlebars

while working with in [express](https://expressjs.com) with [express-handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars) as view engine and [handlebars helpers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars-helpers#forEach). where i have created small partial for select tags but it rending plain key as string.

**My Select Partials select.hbs file**

```
<select name="" id="">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  {{#forEach this.select_values}}
    <option value="{{../this.opt_value}}"> {{ ../this.opt_label }} </option>
  {{/forEach}}
</select>
```

passing array of object in *accounts*

```
accounts: [
      {
        name: 'John',
        email: 'john@example.com'
      },
      {
        name: 'Malcolm',
        email: 'malcolm@example.com'
      },
      {
        name: 'David',
        email: 'david@example.com'
      }
    ]
```

Calling partials in layout

```
{{> modules/select select_values=accounts opt_value='name' opt_label='email'}}
```

I am using bellow dependencies for

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.18.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.15.5",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.0.0",
    "handlebars-helpers": "^0.10.0",
    "hbs": "^4.0.1",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.4.5"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with handlebars [builtin helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html) **lookup** 
added default `{{#each}}` loop from handlebars.

```
<select name="" id="">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  {{#each this.select_values}}
    <option value="{{lookup this ../this.opt_value}}"> {{lookup this  ../this.opt_label }} </option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

Special thanks for @[Tamlyn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/132208/tamlyn) for explanation on lookup helper.

Comment: The code in your example does _not_ use the lookup helper.

Comment: My bad pasted old code 
Will make it correct 
Thanks